# Termstore navigation by CSV file

Tags: navigation

I am creating termsets in the term store that will be used for navigation. Under the intended use section the option "Use this term set for site navigation" is checked.

Is is possible to create this by csv file rather than having to type this manually each time.

I am using Sharepoint 2013 online.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can import terms from a file

https://support.office.com/client/Import-term-sets-168fbc86-7fce-4288-9a1f-b83fc3921c18

1. Sign in to Office 365 with your work or school account.
2. Go to the SharePoint admin center.
3. Select Term Store to open the Term Store management tool.
4. Select the taxonomy in the tree view pane on the left.
5. On the General tab of the properties pane, in the Sample Import section, select View a sample import file.
6. In the File Download dialog box, select Save, and select the location where you want to save the file.
7. Open the sample import file that you have downloaded.
8. Study the file to become familiar with the hierarchy of a term set.
9. To add terms, delete all rows in the CSV except the first, and then enter the information for the terms that you want to use.
10. Open the Term Store Management Tool.
11. In the tree view pane on the left, expand the groups to find the group where you want to import the term set.
12. Point to the group, select the arrow that appears, and then select Import Term Set.
13. In the Term set import dialog box, select Browse, locate the import file that you have updated with the term set values, and then select Open.
14. In the Term set import dialog box, select OK.

Comment: Important to note that this creates only a basic term set not a navigation term set so you will have to go and add all the pages in the Term-Driven Pages tab for every term by hand